# How Active search on DrawerList?

Tags: android, drawer

I create a `DrawerLayout` and it have a `EditText` above of `ListView` for search on `ListView` . How i can active search on `DrawerLayout` now ?

Comment: you mean search using Edittext from ListView?

Comment: Yes. I insert a EditText on DrawerLayout for search on DrawerLayout.

Comment: Did you try anything? Please show that. You can go with implementing onTextChanged listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine for me:

In xml, include an edittext just above the listview:

```
<EditText 
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/searchTxt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
/>
```

In java file:

```
mSearchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adapter.getFilter().filter(s); 
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Here `mSearchText` is the `searchTxt` from xml file and `adapter` will be the adapter of your navigation drawer listview.

Hope it helps.